# Xpath: non-unique node names in XML

Tags: xml, xpath

I have been asked to write a program to parse the below XML..

```
<crowd_response_row i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <crowd_response_data>
            <crowd_response_data>
                <project_id>184472</project_id>
                <approval_status_code>Pending</approval_status_code>
            </crowd_response_data>
            <crowd_response_data>
                <project_id>184475</project_id>
                <approval_status_code>Approved</approval_status_code>
            </crowd_response_data>
```

In my program (which is written in web-harvest), the only way to get the data is with an xpath expression..

```
<xpath expression="//crowd_response_data">
```

The problem is because there are 2 kinds of nodes with that name, my program is picking up both nodes when I only need the child node (the one which has the data).

Is it possible to modify that xpath expression to only get the child or do I need to change the original XML so that each node has unique name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Limiting the query

> Is it possible to modify that xpath expression to only get the child?

You could use a predicate to limit to `<crowd_response_data/>` elements which have a `<project_id/>` child by using

```
//crowd_response_data[project_id]
```

or query all `<crowd_response_data/>` elements that are children of another `<crowd_response_data/>` node:

```
//crowd_response_data/crowd_response_data
```

#### Fixing the data

> Or do I need to change the original XML so that each node has unique name?

If you can do, this might be the better idea and safe you from other problems later. What about a `<crowd_responses/>` element as container?

```
    <crowd_responses>
        <crowd_response_data>
            <project_id>184472</project_id>
            <approval_status_code>Pending</approval_status_code>
        </crowd_response_data>
        <crowd_response_data>
            <project_id>184475</project_id>
            <approval_status_code>Approved</approval_status_code>
        </crowd_response_data>
    </crowd_responses>
```

Comment: Thanks Jens, this answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

The `//` (double forward slash) will get *all* nodes recursively, you can use:

```
/crowd_response_row/crowd_response_data
```

...to get just the parent node, or:

```
//crowd_response_data/crowd_response_data
```

...to get *any* `crowd_response_data` node that's a child of another `crowd_response_data` node.

If you wanted to get a *specific* child node by index, you could use square brackets:

```
/crowd_response_row/crowd_response_data/crowd_response_data[1]
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, this answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to pull out just the elements you're after would probably be

```
/crowd_response_row/crowd_response_data/crowd_response_data
```

but for a simpler expression you could use `//crowd_response_data/crowd_response_data` to get just the `crowd_response_data` elements that are themselves a child of another `crowd_response_data`, or `/*/*/crowd_response_data` for all `crowd_response_data` elements that are at the third level down from the root of the document.

Comment: Thanks Ian, this answers my question.